# How to split this string and append to a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary

I have this string in python code:

```
String = "{a,b,c}{d,e,f}{g,h,i}"
```

I want convert that string to a list like this:

```
list =[{a,b,c},{d,e,f},{g,h,i}]
```

Comment: note, the expected result is is not valid list. all elements of sets??? are not defined.

Comment: I'm assuming this is a list of sets?

Comment: Does the String actually have real values that could be evaluated as set data? As @buran has correctly pointed out, your required output is not possible without values for a->i

Answer (score 1):

Remove the leading and trailing braces, then split the string into groups using '}{' as the separator.  Form a set with each group by splitting them further using ',' as the separator.

```
String = "{a,b,c}{d,e,f}{g,h,i}"

result = [set(g.split(",")) for g in String[1:-1].split("}{")]

print(result)
[{'c', 'a', 'b'}, {'e', 'd', 'f'}, {'g', 'h', 'i'}]
```

*Note that in order to preserve the order of elements within groups, you cannot convert to a set.  Just use the result of the split directly:*

```
result = [g.split(",") for g in String[1:-1].split("}{")]

print(result)
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

*I'm also assuming that you meant to have quotes around the letters in your, otwherwise invalid, expected output*

Answer (score -2):

First allow me to fix your list which seems two-dimensional list, and surround each character with single quotes:

```py
>>> string = "[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]"
>>> import ast
>>> list = ast.literal_eval(string)
>>> type(list)
<type 'list'>
>>> list[0][1]
'b'
```

Here I used ast's `literal_eval`, while you can get the same results with `eval`, however, eval is dangerous especially if you don't trust the user's input.

Comment: Note that neither the input, nor the output is what OP posted/wants.

Comment: A 'dangerous' solution that produces a different output using a different input is not very helpful.